# Script to replace a match of lines - MacOS, zsh

Tags: bash, sed, zsh

I'm trying to finalise a little script to create my custom React environment and install my peerdeps with my desired configuration of eslint/prettier, but I'm not able to finish the very last step, namely replacing these lines from `package.json`:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
```

with these:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "@gbrachetta/eslint-config"
},
"prettier": "@gbrachetta/prettier-config",
```

I tried `sed` to replace line by line, but so far managed this:

```
FILE="package.json"
sed -i '' 's/"react-app",/"@gbrachetta\/eslint-config"/g' $FILE
sed -i '' 's/"react-app\/jest"//g' $FILE
```

This currently produces:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "@gbrachetta/eslint-config"
    
  ]
},
```

My **unachieved** tasks are:

- Remove the empty line left by the second `sed` command.
- Insert the line `"prettier": "@gbrachetta/prettier-config",` right after the closing curly brace + comma.

I am on MacOS, and on zsh. I realise that some `sed` commands work different for my setting.

Would love to know how to achieve this little task!

Comment: You don't need two `sed` calls, you can give multiple commands to a single call.

Comment: Do you have to do this with `sed`? The file is JSON, so it would be better to use `jq` to parse it and create the result.

Comment: Oh it doesn't need to be sed. I'm not handy with scripting. I would use any method that would work from my bash script.

Comment: Is the place at which the `prettier` field is inserted matter ? would it be ok if it's inserted at the end of the file ?

Comment: That would be fine too!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with this:

```
cat <<< $(jq '.eslintConfig={extends: "@gbrachetta/eslint-config"}' package.json) > package.json
cat <<< $(jq '.+ {prettier: "@gbrachetta/prettier-config"}' package.json) > package.json
```

Perhaps there are better ways, but this is working fine.
Many thanks to the comments pointing at `jq`!

Comment: Quick tip : you can chain jq calls like so : `cat <<< $(jq '.eslintConfig.extends= "@gbrachetta/eslint-config" | .prettier="@gbrachetta/prettier-config"' package.json) > package.json`

Comment: Great, thank you for this tip! In my case this worked, though: `cat <<< $(jq '.eslintConfig.extends="@gbrachetta/eslint-config" | .+ {prettier: "@gbrachetta/prettier-config"}' package.json) > package.json`